# Duplicating PostgreSQL's window functions like lag, lead, over

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How do I change a PostgreSQL query into a mongodb bson call?   I have the same use case  listed at  http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2011-10/msg00157.php  I would like to calculate the delta time between two log entries by using something like lag or lead.  Is there anything similar in mongodb to Postgres' lag / lead syntax?

```
select 
  index, 
  starttime, 
  endtime, 
  starttime - lag(endtime) over(order by starttime asc) as delta 
from test
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html

I was looking at http://www.mongovue.com/2010/11/03/yet-another-mongodb-map-reduce-tutorial/ and it seems that *map* / *reduce* / *finalize* should do it. *Map* the id, start and end time, *reduce* does nothing, then do a inner join on its self (the double `for`s) during the *finalize*. I can almost, kind of, sort of, see it...

Answer (score 1):

This is something you'll have to do in your application. Right now, mongoDB doesn't support anything like this.

Comment: Slightly changed the original question with a new map/reduce/finalize idea

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite some of the window functions as subqueries. See if that's possible in the aggregation framework.  This subquery should after the filtering and grouping are done.

Couchbase is going to have the standard window functions. https://blog.couchbase.com/on-par-with-window-functions-in-n1ql/